# How to Edit Uploaded Image in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to edit existing image but I could not update .Please can anyone help me.

I have used my form type in this way

```
$builder->add('picture', FileType::class,['label'=> 'Picture', 'required'=> false, 'data_class'=> null]);
    $builder->add('submit',SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit', 'attr' => ['class'=>'contact100-form-btn']]);
```

I have following entity

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $picture;
```

I have used my form handling in this way

```
$form = $this->createForm(userType::class, $userEntity, ['action'=>$actionUrl]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        dump($form->getData());die;}
```

Now when I am using  this form in twig `{{ form_widget(form.picture) }}` the value is missing in input field `<input type= "file" name= "picture">` I am not getting value of existing image on upload button.

controller for edit action

```
public function editUserData(Request $request, $id) {

    $userEntity = $this->get('app.manage.user_data')->getUserById($id);
    $actionUrl = $this->generateUrl('edit_user_data', ['id' => $id]);
    $form = $this->createForm(userType::class, $userEntity, ['action' => $actionUrl]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        dump($form->getData());die;
        $this->addOrEditUserData($userEntity, $form, $id);
        $this->addFlash("success", "Your have successfully changes data of id=" . $id);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('display_user_data'));
    }

    return $this->render('@LillyDoo/Narayan/_edit.userData.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()

    ]);
}
```

Please can any help me how I can update existing image.

Thanks

Comment: try it ::$form->get('picture')->getData());

Comment: which symfony version you use ?

Comment: and can you show up your controller action code

Comment: @mohammed I am using symfony 3.4 version and I am using controller action in this way `public function editUserData(Request $request, $id) `

Comment: no i mean the code in the action  editUserData(Request $request, $id) , can you show it

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI can you please check on answer section I have posted my controller code there

Comment: @ShreeyaGautam , please add the code in the description not in comment section , i'm writing for you the response in a while ok

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI now I have added code on my post. I am hoping to get solution from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example for updating a file for a given entity : 
in your example , try this :

In your entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" , "image/png" , "image/tiff" , "image/svg+xml"})
 */
private $picture;
```

Here we are storing the name of the file as string in the database while the file is upload using for example a service that allow you to manage uploading files in a specific directory.

your entity type :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('picture', null , array("attr"=> array(), 'required' => false));
}
```

i set the second param to null because i have been specified that it will a file input in the entity annotation .

> we suppose that the files you upload are on the /web/uploads

your controller should be seem somethign like  :

```
/**  
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="your_route_name")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request,$id)
    {
      $userEntity = $this->get('app.manage.user_data')->getUserById($id);
      $userEntity = $this->get('app.manage.user_data')->getUserById($id);
      $actionUrl = $this->generateUrl('edit_user_data', ['id' => $id]);
      $editForm= $this->createForm(userType::class, $userEntity, ['action' => 
    $actionUrl]);


      // we must transform the image string from Db  to File to respect the form types
       $oldFileName = $userEntity->getPicture();
       $oldFileNamePath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/'.$userEntity->getPicture();
       $pictureFile = new File($oldFileNamePath);
       $userEntity->setPicture($pictureFile );

       $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            /*
           *  it means that the user has been set a new picture
           *  else :
           *  we let the old picture
           */
            if($userEntity->getPicture()!=null){
                $newLogoFile = $userEntity->getPicture();
               $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$newLogoFile ->guessExtension();

             $newLogoFile ->move($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/', $fileName);
                $newFileName = $fileUploader->upload($newLogoFile);
                $userEntity->setPicture($newFileName);
                $fileUploader->deleteFile($oldFileNamePath);
            }
            /**
             * setting the picturefile because the file is not set . we modify it using the old file name .
             */
            else{
                $userEntity->setPicture($oldFileName);
            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    }
```

I hope that help you . if you still have problems , just comment

Answer (score 0):

Because you specify data_class => null on "picture" input it will not map it to your entity, so remove it and it will work.

If you do not want to have it mapped on the entity then pedram's comment is correct.

See the docs for data_class at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html#creating-form-classes -> Setting the data_class

Comment: If I will remove `data_class=>null` and receiving these type of error msg and `The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
` so I have to set `data_class => null`  in order to remove this error

Comment: The best way is to recommend you to read the official documentation on how to handle file uploads with symfony+doctrine. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/upload_file.html